# Embedding a Flash Game using html. Cant figure out why my code wont work

Tags: html, embed, flash

Here is my code. I tried alot of things. This code works for some games but why not this game?

[Here is the game link.](http://poiuyt.flscntntdn.eu/swf/winpalace/flash/mini_flash_client.swf?user=&sPassword=&token=&encrypted=&forReal=false&IP=190.4.91.2&portBase=0&language=en&casinoName=WinPalace&gameid=18&machid=2&handcount=&denom=&showVersion=false)

```
 <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="Yourfilename.swf">
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
    <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
    <EMBED src="http://poiuyt.flscntntdn.eu/swf/winpalace/flash/mini_flash_client.swf?user=&sPassword=&token=&encrypted=&forReal=false&IP=190.4.91.2&portBase=0&language=en&casinoName=WinPalace&gameid=18&machid=2&handcount=&denom=&showVersion=false" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: What browser you've tested?

Comment: and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The game does not load. I only get the background blue screen. (#333399)